# AS3: trace statement doesn't work in inheritor's constructor

Tags: actionscript-3, constructor

I've recently become a part of a major project in AS3 which has been worked on for a couple of years now and being a fairly large project with a lot of code, It got me stuck on something that I have trouble understanding. It's about two classes, one of which is a 'super' class of the other one, which I'll call "inheritor" from now on. It looks something like this:

the inherited/super class:

```
public class TVset
{
    public function TVset()
    {
        trace("I am the super class", this);
    }
}
```

the inheritor class:

```
public class Brand1 extends TVset
{
    public function Brand1()
    {
        trace("I am the inheritor", this);
    }
}
```

Now, I know that if I write this code

```
var aNewTV:Brand1 = new Brand1();
```

this is the output we'd normally expect

```
I am the super class, [class Brand1]
I am the inheritor, [class Brand1]
```

but I only get

```
I am the super class, [class Brand1]
```

None of the code in the inheritor's constructor is being executed, and yet it does call it's super class. Does anybody have an idea why would that happen?

Comment: It will be more logical if you will see `"I am the inheritor, [class Brand1]"`

Comment: You're right, I've corrected it.

Comment: :) if so , i have an answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to make another correction - I had written it correctly the first time. I'll add a comment to your answer as well.

Comment: I guess this can be due to some exception in code from parent constructor

Comment: and what if you try to call `super()` in the inheritor's constructor after the `trace` ? actually see if it running at all

Comment: Nope, still the same. The inheritor's trace() is being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if there is an error in the code it will stop reading the code from that point on instead of ending the program. What I would try do is move the trace statement from the beginning of the super class to the end and see if it no longer traces. Then using that method you can move it up and down till you have found the exact line where the program stops running.

This method has worked with quite a few of my problem and I hope this helps with yours.

note: Sometimes there will be an error that the compiler wont pick up and that is where I use this.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting a runtime error that is preventing the expected results. I get the feeling we are not seeing everything.

Fix the runtime error and this should work as expected.